# Manager dict in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Here is a simple multiprocessing code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()

def f():
    d[1].append(4)
    print d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d[1] = []
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Output I get is:

```
{1: []}
```

Why don't I get `{1: [4]}` as the output?

Comment: I found this: http://bugs.python.org/issue6766. Is there a patch available?

Comment: [`manager.list()` doesn't help](http://ideone.com/aviB2)

Answer (score 41):

Here is what you wrote:

```
# from here code executes in main process and all child processes
# every process makes all these imports
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

# every process creates own 'manager' and 'd'
manager = Manager() 
# BTW, Manager is also child process, and 
# in its initialization it creates new Manager, and new Manager
# creates new and new and new
# Did you checked how many python processes were in your system? - a lot!
d = manager.dict()

def f():
    # 'd' - is that 'd', that is defined in globals in this, current process 
    d[1].append(4)
    print d

if __name__ == '__main__':
# from here code executes ONLY in main process 
    d[1] = []
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Here is what you should have written:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
def f(d):
    d[1] = d[1] + [4]
    print d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager() # create only 1 mgr
    d = manager.dict() # create only 1 dict
    d[1] = []
    p = Process(target=f,args=(d,)) # say to 'f', in which 'd' it should append
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: That doesn't actually work, you get: `{1: []}` instead of `{1: [4]}`

Comment: @crysis405 I fixed that. Looks like manager's dict is not fully dumped while transfering between processes, so we need to replace original value with other list with another id.

Comment: @akaRem, you saved my day, this should be stated very clearly somewhere that Manager() should be single global object for the whole application

Comment: @akaRem, Can I assigne some existing dictionary here? For example, in place of `d[1]=[]`, how can I do `d = d1`, where d1 is some existing dictionary. I think it will replace the manager class at all.

Comment: @MikePatel Nope, it doesn't work. I tried something similar, and it failed. The managerized dict is a proxy/channel among processes. That's why it has to be a mutable container. You can put in data in this proxy container, but things would go awry if you want to assign itself in the new/child process with another dict.

Comment: @MaximGalushka I likewise missed that for an inordinate amount of time... it actually looks to be a windows specific thing... Windows forks, causing it to make a copy by reloading the script in another instance... but that of course reloads the calls to things like Mananger, unless set aside in the __main__ clause stuff

Answer (score 27):

The reason that the new item appended to `d[1]` is not printed is stated in [*Python*'s official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list):

> Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will
> not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of
> knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item,
> you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy.

Therefore, this is actually what happens:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()

def f():
    # invoke d.__getitem__(), returning a local copy of the empty list assigned by the main process,
    # (consider that a KeyError exception wasn't raised, so a list was definitely returned),
    # and append 4 to it, however this change is not propagated through the manager,
    # as it's performed on an ordinary list with which the manager has no interaction
    d[1].append(4)
    # convert d to string via d.__str__() (see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__),
    # returning the "remote" string representation of the object (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list),
    # to which the change above was not propagated
    print d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # invoke d.__setitem__(), propagating this assignment (mapping 1 to an empty list) through the manager
    d[1] = []
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Reassigning `d[1]` with a new list, or even with the same list once again, after it was updated, triggers the manager to propagate the change:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()

def f():
    # perform the exact same steps, as explained in the comments to the previous code snippet above,
    # but in addition, invoke d.__setitem__() with the changed item in order to propagate the change
    l = d[1]
    l.append(4)
    d[1] = l
    print d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d[1] = []
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The line `d[1] += [4]` would have worked as well.

---

### EDIT for *Python 3.6* or later:

[Since *Python 3.6*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#multiprocessing), per [this changeset](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/39e7307f9aee) following [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue6766), it's also possible to [use nested Proxy Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) which automatically propagate any changes performed on them to the containing Proxy Object. Thus, replacing the line `d[1] = []` with `d[1] = manager.list()` would correct the issue as well:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()

def f():
    d[1].append(4)
    # the __str__() method of a dict object invokes __repr__() on each of its items,
    # so explicitly invoking __str__() is required in order to print the actual list items
    print({k: str(v) for k, v in d.items()})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d[1] = manager.list()
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Unfortunately, this bug fix was not ported to *Python 2.7* (as of *Python 2.7.13*).

---

### NOTE (running under the *Windows* operating system):

Although the described behaviour applies to the *Windows* operating system as well, the attached code snippets would fail when executed under *Windows*  due to the [different process creation mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), that relies on the [`CreateProcess()` API rather than the `fork()` system call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13839935/3903832), which isn't supported.

Whenever a new process is created via the *multiprocessing* module, *Windows* creates a fresh *Python* interpreter process that imports the main module, with potentially hazardous side effects. In order to circumvent this issue, the following programming guideline is [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods):

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new *Python* interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).

Therefore, executing the attached code snippets as is under *Windows* would try to create an infinite number of processes due to the `manager = Manager()` line. This can be easily fixed by creating the `Manager` and `Manager.dict` objects inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause and passing the `Manager.dict` object as an argument to `f()`, as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536888/3903832).

More details on the issue may be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236445/3903832).

Answer (score 13):

I think this is a bug in manager proxy calls. You can circumvent avoiding call methods of shared list, like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()

def f():
    # get the shared list
    shared_list = d[1]

    shared_list.append(4)

    # forces the shared list to 
    # be serialized back to manager
    d[1] = shared_list

    print d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d[1] = []
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This simple example helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()
l=manager.list()

def f():
    l.append(4)
    d[1]=l
    print d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d[1]=[]
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might solve the askers problem it doesn't explain why. It would be good to add some explanation.