# Problem in writing the output of a differntial equation with multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, differential-equations

I am entirely new to parallel computing, in fact, to numerical methods. I am trying to solve a differential equation using python `solve_ivp` of the following form:

```
y''(x) + (a^2 + x^2)y(x) = 0
y(0)=1
y'(0)=0
x=(0,100)
```

I want to solve for a range of `a` and write a file as `a[i] y[i](80)`.

The original Equation is quite complicated but essentially the structure is the same as defined above. I have used a `for` loop and it is taking a lot of time for computation. Searching online I came across this beautiful website and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945124/how-to-make-the-python-code-with-two-for-loop-run-fasteris-there-a-python-way-o) and related answer that preciously may solve the problem I am facing.

**I tried the original code provided in the solution; however, the output produced is not properly sorted.** I mean, the second column is not in proper order.

```
q1    a1    Y1
q1    a2    Y3
q1    a4    Y4
q1    a3    Y3
q1    a5    Y5
...
```

I have even tried with one loop with one parameter, but the same issue still remains. Below is my code with the same multiprocessing method but with `solve_ivp`

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def fun(t, y):
    # replace this function with whatever function you want to work with
    #    (this one is the example function from the scipy docs for odeint)
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -a*omega - q*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt

#definitions of work thread and write thread functions
tspan = np.linspace(0, 10, 201)


def run_thread(input_queue, output_queue):
    # run threads will pull tasks from the input_queue, push results into output_queue
    while True:
        try:
            queueitem = input_queue.get(block = False)
            if len(queueitem) == 3:
                a, q, t = queueitem
                sol = solve_ivp(fun, [tspan[0], tspan[-1]], [1, 0], method='RK45', t_eval=tspan)
                F = 1 + sol.y[0].T[157]
                output_queue.put((q, a, F))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            print("Queue exhausted, terminating")
            break

def write_thread(queue):    
    # write thread will pull results from output_queue, write them to outputfile.txt
    f1 = open("outputfile.txt", "w")
    while True:
        try:
            queueitem = queue.get(block = False)
            if queueitem[0] == "TERMINATE":
                f1.close()
                break
            else:
                q, a, F = queueitem                
                print("{}  {} {} \n".format(q, a, F))            
                f1.write("{}  {} {} \n".format(q, a, F))            
        except:
            # necessary since it will throw an error whenever output_queue is empty
            pass

# define time point sequence            
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 201)

# prepare input and output Queues
mpM = mp.Manager()
input_queue = mpM.Queue()
output_queue = mpM.Queue()

# prepare tasks, collect them in input_queue
for q in np.linspace(0.0, 4.0, 100):
    for a in np.linspace(-2.0, 7.0, 100):
        # Your computations as commented here will now happen in run_threads as defined above and created below
        # print('Solving for q = {}, a = {}'.format(q,a))
        # sol1 = scipy.integrate.odeint(fun, [1, 0], t, args=( a, q))[..., 0]
        # print(t[157])
        # F = 1 + sol1[157]    
        input_tupel = (a, q, t)
        input_queue.put(input_tupel)

# create threads
thread_number = mp.cpu_count()
procs_list = [mp.Process(target = run_thread , args = (input_queue, output_queue)) for i in range(thread_number)]         
write_proc = mp.Process(target = write_thread, args = (output_queue,))

# start threads
for proc in procs_list:
    proc.start()
write_proc.start()

# wait for run_threads to finish
for proc in procs_list:
    proc.join()

# terminate write_thread
output_queue.put(("TERMINATE",))
write_proc.join()
```

Kindly let me know what is wrong in the multiprocessing so that I can learn a bit about multiprocessing in python in the process. Also, I would much appreciate if anyone let me know about the most elegant/efficient way(s) for handling such a computation in python. Thanks

Comment: Please tell more detail

Comment: @Minh-ThanhHoang, in the outputfile.txt file, the data is not written in proper order. The output is supposed to be written in ascending order in (q,a) but sometimes that is not maintained if I use multiple cores.

Comment: Why would you *expect* concurrent processes to preserve the order of the data?

Comment: @DavisHerring, I don't expect it to preserve the order, in fact, to be absolutely honest I can't say I have completely understood what is going on in the multiprocessing. This is my first-time encounter with such processes. However, I want it so that I don't need any post-processing before plotting the data.

Comment: @new_kid: Is the output so large that you can’t just buffer and sort it?

Comment: @DavisHerring, I will be generating many large outputs, thus it will be inconvenient to post-process each of them every time. I have seen some parallel codes written in C++ where such an issue has been properly addressed. Then why can't they be sorted in python!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something of an [online](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) **sort**.  In this case, you know the **order** in which you want to present results (*i.e.*, the input order), so just accumulate the outputs in a [priority queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) and pop elements from it when they **match** the next key you’re expecting.

A trivial example without showing the parallelism:

```
import heapq
def sort_follow(pairs,ref):
  """
  Sort (a prefix of) pairs so as to have its first components
  be the elements of (sorted) ref in order.
  Uses memory proportional to the disorder in pairs.
  """
  heap=[]
  pairs=iter(pairs)
  for r in ref:
    while not heap or heap[0][0]!=r:
      heapq.heappush(heap,next(pairs))
    yield heapq.heappop(heap)
```

The virtue of this approach—the reduced memory footprint—is probably **irrelevant** for small results of just a few floats, but it’s easy enough to apply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, at the level of my expertise, I may not be able to implement it soon. It would be very helpful if you kindly provide a working example(even with one for loop) which I can test.