# Speeding up launch of processes using multiprocessing in case of Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a machine learning application in Python. And I'm using the `multiprocessing` module in Python to parallelize some of the work (specifically feature computation).

Now, `multiprocessing` works differently on Unix variants, and Windows OS.
`Unix (mac/linux):`  fork/forkserver/spawn
`Windows:` spawn
[Why multiprocessing.Process behave differently on windows and linux for global object and function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236211/why-multiprocessing-process-behave-differently-on-windows-and-linux-for-global-o)

Because of `spawn` being used on Windows, the launch of multiprocessing processes is really slow. It loads all the modules from scratch for each process on Windows.

Is there a way to speed up the creation of the extra processes on Windows? (using threads instead of multiple processes is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple new processes each time, I highly suggest using [concurrent.futures `ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) and leaving the executor open in the background.

That way, you don't create a new process each time, but rather leave them open in the background and pass some work using the module's functions or queues and pipes.

Bottom line - Don't create new processes each time. Leave them open and pass work.