# Python multiprocessing to execute scripts instead of function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

1) Does the `multiprocessing` module support Python script files I can use to start a second process instead of a function?

Currently I use `multiprocessing.Process` which takes a function but I would like to execute `foo.py` instead. I could use `subprocess.Popen` but the benefit of `multiprocessing.Process` is that I can pass objects (even if they are just pickled).

When I use multiprocessing.Process, why is my_module imported in the child process but print("foo") is not executed?

2) When I use `multiprocessing.Process`, why is `my_module` imported in the child process but `print("foo")` is not executed? How is my_module available although the main scope is not executed?

```
import multiprocessing
import my_module
print("foo")

def worker():
    print("bar")
    my_module.foo()
    return

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(1,2, d))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: Three specific questions are better than a single juggernaut question.

Comment: Editing the question(s) to be very different than the original is also not great, since some answers might have already addressed your original question(s).

Comment: A vicious circle it is now.. :-/

Comment: I restored one question for completeness

Comment: Keep in mind that the implementation of the multiprocessing module on Windows and UNIX/Linux behave differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no obvious difference between a Python function and a routine you want to run in another process. Functions are just procedures.

Say if another script file (`foo.py` in this context) you wished to run in another process has following:

```
# for demonstration only
from stuff import do_things

a = 'foo'
b = 1
do_things(a, b) # it doesn't matter what this does
```

You could refactor `foo.py` this way

```
from stuff import do_things

def foo():
    a = 'foo'
    b = 1
    do_things(a, b)
```

And in the module you are spawning the process:

```
from foo import foo

p = multiprocess.Process(target=foo)
# ...
```

`Process` API requires that a "callable" is provided as a `target`. If say you tried to provided the module `foo` (where `foo.py` is the first version without a function `foo`):

```
import foo
p = Process(target=foo)
p.start()
```

You will get a `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` error for a good reason. Imagine when you import `foo` module it eagerly executes right away since it's not wrapped inside a function/procedure aka `callable`. Try inserting a print statement in a module file and import it. Module-level statements are evaluated right away.

This answers question number 2:

When you imported `my_module` at the top level, it's imported once per module, even if `worker` was not executed. `my_module` was available to `worker` because `worker` procedure [closes over `my_module`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). 
When you pass a subroutine like `worker` to a concurrent process, there is no guarantee when it will be called or even will ever be.

You could import a module any where in a Python module, including within a function/subroutine. But doing so in this case might not be optimal or necessary.

Comment: Awesome, that answers my questions! Thanks

Comment: Great answer, but to number 2, the implementation and its behaviour completely differs on Win and Linux/Unix. Worth to mention that `foo` indeed gets printed on Windows 5 times, since the process is not forked and rather restarted

Comment: @seb-mtl could you elaborate? Why did it print exactly 5 times?

Comment: multiprocessing forks the process, so you have a clone. But processes execute different paths afterwards. But on Windows there is no real `fork` so it gets simulated in Python by the "closest" behaviour possible which results in that Python executes the entire same module again, and executes the function afterwards

Comment: To explain that in detail a comment is not the right place but I found a great answer which covers exacly that. Look for the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236211/why-multiprocessing-process-behave-differently-on-windows-and-linux-for-global-o

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiprocessing.pool() and the pass the function inside the method which you want to execute. I have personally used it as you can split the data into multiple parts and also have the flexibility to use the number of cpu.

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: from multiprocessing import Pool
pool=Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count()) objs=pool.imap_unordered(Inter_method, (np.array_split(Interchange_df, 5, axis=0))). In this case i am using the pool class of multiprocessing and imap method of that class. Inter_method is my function which i wanted to use and then i am splitting the dataframe into 5 parts. You can tweak this according to your requirements