# Speeding up Pandas Apply for API Calls with Requests

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I have a list of IP addresses in a df. These IP addresses are sent in GET requests to the ARIN database using `requests`, and I am interested in getting the organization or customer of that IP address. I am using a `requests` `Session()` inside of a `requests-futures` `FuturesSession()` to hopefully speed up the API calls. Here is the code:

```
s = requests.Session()
session = FuturesSession(session=s, max_workers=10)

def getIPAddressOrganization(IP_Address):
    url = 'https://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/' + IP_Address + '.json'
    request = session.get(url)
    response = request.result().json()
    try:
        organization = response['net']['orgRef']['@name']
    except KeyError:
        organization = response['net']['customerRef']['@name']
    return organization

df['organization'] = df['IP'].apply(getIPAddressOrganization)
```

Adding the regular `requests` `Session()` helped performance a lot, but the `requests-futures` `FuturesSession()` has not helped (likely due to my lack of knowledge).

How should `pandas` `apply()` be used in tandem with `requests-futures`, and/or is there another option for speeding up API calls that could be more effective?

Comment: When I need to download resources from a pandas dataframe, I'll use a column method, like df['column'].tolist() and set that equal to a variable, then I'll use threads or multiprocessing to efficiently make the requests and then map the result back into the dataframe.

Comment: sounds like a decent option - could you please expound upon that?

Comment: Right, I just meant, take the pandas column with all your org IPS, put it in a list. Process the list using requests futures, or the multiprocessing module using a strategy like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640367/python-manager-dict-in-multiprocessing, incorporating a process safe dict to map the IP address to your JSON parsing fun and then in pandas, df['result'] = df['ip'].map(lambda x: mydict.get(x, None))

Comment: so it's not possible to multiprocess a df column? in other words, the requests futures really isn't doing anything in my current code?

Comment: That's my thinking  - pandas may not move to the next row until a value has been returned from the function called.

Comment: An easy way to verify would be to write a stupid function that sleeps for 5 seconds and returns True, then run for a dataframe with 10 rows and see if it takes 50 seconds, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer the question, but it shows that pandas' `apply()` function does indeed wait for the result of each API call and does not parallelize or optimize for IO time:

```py
import time
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(10))
start = time.perf_counter()
df.apply(lambda r: time.sleep(5), axis=1)
end = time.perf_counter() - start

print(f'total time: {end}')
```

> total time: 50.05315346799034

**Conclusion** - perhaps it's best to consider an async IO approach

A tentative direction:

```py
async def parallel_rest_calls(data: List):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for ip in data:
            tasks.append(getIPAddressOrganization(session=session, ip)

        enriched_data_col = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        return enriched_data_col


async def getIPAddressOrganization(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, IP_Address):
    url = 'https://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/' + IP_Address + '.json'
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params) as response:
        json = await response.json()
        status = response.status
        
        try:
            organization = json['net']['orgRef']['@name']
        except KeyError:
            organization = json['net']['customerRef']['@name']
        return (IP_Address, organization)
```